# How do I update selected values in react multiselect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, multi-select

I have a modal in which I edit my model. In my form, I also have a multi-select tag field. The "tags" is an array of objects with labels and values as show below.

There is a dummy tags object (mimicking a database) which all the tags are selected from.

```
const dummyTags = [
        { label: "Test 1", value: "Test 1" },
        { label: "Test 2", value: "Test 2" },
        { label: "Test 3", value: "Test 3" },
    ];
```

So, if I selected "Test 1" and "Test 2", my tags array becomes (only the values are then saved in the database):

```
const tgs = [
        {
            label: "Test 1",
            value: "Test 1"
        },
        {
            label: "Test 2",
            value: "Test 2"
        }
    ];
```

However, during update, the tags come from the database as `['Test 1','Test 2']`.

I want to use the tags from the database shown in the line above to compare the `dummyTags` array so I can have a new array of objects with values like the `tgs` array above.

At the moment, this is what I am doing:

```
let newtags = [];
if (groupTags.length > 0) { //groupTags is the tags from the database
    groupTags?.forEach((tag) => {
    newtags.push({ label: tag, value: tag });
    });
}
```

This works, but I think it's not reliable. What if the label and value are not the same for a particular tag?

Is there a better way of implementing this?

Comment: not sure if I understood correctly, but `the tags come from the database as ['Test 1','Test 2']` tags are labels or values ? or what is the expected o/p

Comment: @KcH, only values of the tags are saved to and returned from the database

Comment: can you add expected input & output please ? sorry I couldn't understand 

Comment: Maybe he wants to say, he has a multiselect input that is taking data like this `[{label:'', value: “”}]` but the backend returns data like this `[“Test1 ”, “Test2”]` and he is asking what would be the best way to set the data according to multiselect method. Am I right? @MofoluwashoKolawoleJimoh

Comment: Yes you are right @AhmadFaraz

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ['Test 1','Test 2', 'Test 3']

const result = arr.map(d => ({label: d, value: d}));

console.log(result)
```